# How do I repeatedly update a JLabel with an increasing delay until the delay hits a limit?

Tags: timer, delay, jlabel, sleep, invokelater

I am trying to update my JLabel with the current numbers of a spinning wheel, with an increasing delay that represents the slowing wheel. I've tried Thread.sleep(), Timer, and invokeLater() but I must be doing something terribly wrong as nothing I have tried over the last few days has worked. Thread.sleep results in the GUI only updating the last thing, Timer ignores the delay and prints the results ahead of the spin finishing, and I could not get invokeLater() to update the JLabel at all. What should I be doing?

```
public void spin(int wheelSize, int initialDelay, int finalDelay, int delayIncrement, WheelCallback callback) {

        /**
         * Begins the spin on a random number within the wheelSize
         */
        Random randomNum = new Random();
        int currentNum = randomNum.nextInt((wheelSize - 0) + 1) + 0;
        //frame.setLabel(Integer.toString(currentNum));
        System.out.println(currentNum);
        /**
         * Loops the wheel until the finalDelay is met
         */
        for(int i = initialDelay; i < finalDelay; i += delayIncrement) {
                /**
                 * Causes the delay between numbers
                 */
            try {
                   Thread.sleep(i);
                }
                    catch(InterruptedException e) {
                }

                /**
                 * Increments the number to the next number up on the wheel.
                 * If the number reaches the maximum, it is reset to the minimum
                 */
                currentNum++;
                if(currentNum > wheelSize) {
                    currentNum = 0;
                }

                callback.nextNumber(currentNum, this);
            }       
            callback.result(currentNum, this);
            calculateResult(currentNum);
    }




public void nextNumber(int nextNumber, GameEngine engine) {
        frame.setLabel(Integer.toString(nextNumber));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Swing Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), as described in this thread: [how to update a jLabel every time with a while loop with a delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251675/how-to-update-a-jlabel-every-time-with-a-while-loop-with-a-delay)