# Cannot set JLabel to Multiple Text Values

Tags: java

My JLabel isn't being set to all of these text values.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MultipleLables{
    static JFrame framey;
    static JLabel lbl;
    static JButton btn;

    public static void GUIWindow () {
        framey = new JFrame("Test");
        framey.setSize(100, 100);
        framey.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        lbl = new JLabel("Example Text");
        btn = new JButton("Change Text");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    lbl.setText("First Text");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    lbl.setText("Second Text");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    lbl.setText("Third Text");
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    //Don't really care if the program dies
                }

            }
        });
        framey.add(lbl);
        framey.add(btn);

        framey.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUIWindow();
    }
}
```

The output would waits two seconds, then set the value of the JLabel to "Text Three" instead of displaying the three values one after another.  I don't see what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: The problem you describe is similar to the one explained in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251675/how-to-update-a-jlabel-every-time-with-a-while-loop-with-a-delay). Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

From the question, It is not clear what is the problem you are facing. Please add an example of the code that others can run and test.

If you are trying to see the value of the variables `a`, `b` or 'c' in the JLabel , you will need code like

```
GUIWindow.text.setText(a.toString());
```

What you are doing now is setting the text "a" and not the value of variable `a`. 
I am not sure what is the data type of the variables `a`, `b` or 'c'. If they do have a proper `toString()` implementation (they probably do as the `System.out.println()` is giving you the desired output), the above code should work. Else you might need to call the right method on these variables that will give you the desired text.

Comment: Alright, I'll add my source code of my project to this site

Comment: Can you please re-post using the guidelines in  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Did you try my recommended change n the answer I posted?

Comment: I'm going to re write it to make a window and produce the error

Comment: Good. You will definitely need to change `GUIWindow.text.setText("a");` to `GUIWindow.text.setText(a);`

Comment: Not really.  The sring a is fro testing

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by creating and running a swing timer.  Here is the code, with the fix inside it.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MulttipleLables{
static JFrame framey;
static JLabel lbl;
static JButton btn;
static Timer t;
static int i;

public static void GUIWindow () {
    framey = new JFrame("Test");
    framey.setSize(100, 100);
    framey.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    lbl = new JLabel("Example Text");
    btn = new JButton("Change Text");
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e1) {
            t = new Timer (1000,new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e2) {
                    ;
                    lbl.setText("First Text");
                    switch (i) {
                    case 1:
                        lbl.setText("Second Text");
                        i++;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        lbl.setText("Third Text");
                        i++;
                        break;
                        default:
                            i++;
                    }
                    if (i == 3) {
                        t.stop();
                        i = 0;
                    }
                }
            });
            t.start();
        }
    });
    framey.add(lbl);
    framey.add(btn);

    framey.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GUIWindow();
}
}
```

I don't have a compiler on me, but I am sure this code should work for what you need.